# CSS styling my page, sorry guys im a noob

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have my website code below, however my problem is not with its functionality rather its with its appearance

```js
var name;
var nameFormat = true;
var totalRight=0;
var welcomeName
$("#welcome2").hide();
$("#welcome2-0").hide();
$('form').hide();
$("#MYsubmit").hide();
var score;
function submission() {
    var name = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
  if (name.length > 0) {
    alert("Welcome " + name);
    $("#name").fadeOut(1000);
    $("#welcome").fadeOut(1000);
    $("#welcome2").show();
    $("#welcome2-0").show();
 $('MYsubmit').show();
    $('form').show();
   welcomeName=document.getElementById("welcome3-1").innerHTML +="Welcome "+name+"!"+"Good Luck!";
   
 

  } else {
    nameFormat == false;
    alert("Please enter the name again");
  }



}


var welcomeName=document.getElementById("Question1").innerHTML +="1. How long does it take the average person to fall asleep?";
var welcomeName=document.getElementById("Question2").innerHTML +="2.How many eggs does the average american eat per year?";
var welcomeName=document.getElementById("Question3").innerHTML +="3.How many taste buds does the average american have?";
var welcomeName=document.getElementById("Question4").innerHTML +="4.What is the average lifespan of a squirrel?";
var welcomeName=document.getElementById("Question5").innerHTML +="5.on average __% of all restaurant meals include potato chips";


function finalsubmit() {
if(document.getElementById('correctAnswer-1').checked) {
 totalRight=totalRight+1;

}

if(document.getElementById('correctAnswer-2').checked) {
 totalRight=totalRight+1;

}

if(document.getElementById('correctAnswer-3').checked) {
 totalRight=totalRight+1;

}

if(document.getElementById('correctAnswer-4').checked) {
 totalRight=totalRight+1;
 
}

if(document.getElementById('correctAnswer-5').checked) {
 totalRight=totalRight+1;

}



document.getElementById("score").innerHTML +="RESULT for "+name+"You Scored "+totalRight+" out of 5!"+"<br>";
score=document.getElementById("ans").innerHTML +="You scored "+totalRight+" out of 5";
if(totalRight==5){
 document.getElementById("score").innerHTML +="You score 5/5 PERFECT!";
}

}

/*
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hint1").mouseover(function(){
    $("#hint1").
  });
  $("#hint1").mouseout(function(){
    $("#hint1").
  });
    }); 
*/

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#hint1').hover(function() {
        
    $(this).text("7Minutes");
  },
  function() {
    
    $(this).text("[HINT]");
  });
});


$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#hint2').hover(function() {
        
    $(this).text("263Eggs");
  },
  function() {
    
    $(this).text("[HINT]");
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#hint3').hover(function() {
        
    $(this).text("10,000");
  },
  function() {
    
    $(this).text("[HINT]");
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#hint4').hover(function() {
        
    $(this).text("7Years");
  },
  function() {
    
    $(this).text("[HINT]");
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#hint5').hover(function() {
        
    $(this).text("7%");
  },
  function() {
    
    $(this).text("[HINT]");
  });
});
```

```css
#welcome{
    top:30px;
    left: 30px;
    color: antiquewhite;
    border: 2px solid darkblue;
    background: darkblue;
    padding: 25px;
  
}

#name{
 
    top:30px;
    left: 500px;
    color: antiquewhite;
    background: darkblue;
    border: 25px solid darkblue;
}

body {
    background-color: lightblue;
    color: white;
  }
#welcome2{
 text-align: center;

    color: antiquewhite;
    background: darkblue;
    border: 25px solid darkblue;
}
#welcome3-1{
 top:30px;
    left: 500px;
    color: Aqua;
    background:darkblue;
    border: 25px solid darkblue;
}
#welcome2-0{
 text-align: center;
    color: antiquewhite;
    background: darkblue;
    border: 25px solid darkblue;
}
.Question{
 text-align: left;
    color: antiquewhite;
    background: darkblue;
    border: 25px solid darkblue;
}
.hints{
color: aquamarine;
background: darkblue;
border: 25px solid darkblue;
}
.quiz{
background: darkblue;
}
#ans{
 text-align: left;
 border: 25px solid darkblue;
 background: darkblue;
 color:red;
}
#score{
 
 background-color: yellow;
    color:red;
    background-size: 100px 100px;

}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Welcome!</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/styles.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>

<p>

  <body>
    <div id="welcome"><b>Welcome to the Myanmar Trivia Quiz</b><br> please enter your name and click on "Begin Quiz" to start</div>
    <div id="name"><b>Name:</b>

      <input type="text" id="textbox">
      <button id=”myButton” type="button" onclick="submission()">submit</button>
</div>



<h1 id="welcome2">Myanmar Trivia Quiz </h1>
<div id="welcome2-0">Test your Demographic Knowledge<br>---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------</div>
<div id="welcome3-1"><b></b></div>
<div id="ans"><h3></h3></div>
<form class="quiz">
        <div id="Question1" class="Question"><b></b></div>
        <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="7Minutes" id="correctAnswer-1" class="Answer"> 7 Minutes<br>
        <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="5Minutes" >5 Minutes<br>
        <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="20Minutes" >20 Minutes  <br>
        <input type="radio"name="radiobutton" value="14Minutes" >14 Minutes  <br>
        <div id="hint1" class="hints">[HINT]</div>
</form> 
    <form class="quiz"> 
        <div id="Question2" class="Question"><b></b></div>
        <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="263Eggs" id="correctAnswer-2">263 eggs a year<br>
        <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="23Eggs">23 eggs a year<br>
        <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="100Eggs">100 eggs a year<br>
        <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="45Eggs">45 eggs a year<br>
        <div id="hint2" class="hints">[HINT]</div>
    </form>
  <form class="quiz">  
        <div id="Question3" class="Question"><b></b></div>
        <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="10,000" id="correctAnswer-3">10,000<br>
        <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="4000">4000<br>
        <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="20,000">20,000<br>
        <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="537">537<br>
        <div id="hint3" class="hints">[HINT]</div>
  
  </form>
  <form class="quiz">
  
        <div id="Question4" class="Question"><b></b></div>
        <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="7Years" id="correctAnswer-4"> 7 Years<br>
        <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="5Years">5 Years<br>
        <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="20Years">20 Years  <br>
        <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="14Years">14 Years  <br>
        <div id="hint4" class="hints">[HINT]</div>
    
 <form class="quiz">
        <div id="Question5" class="Question"><b></b></div>
        <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="7%" id="correctAnswer-5"> 7%<br>
        <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="5%">5%<br>
        <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="20%">20%<br>
        <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="14%">14%<br>
        <div id="hint5" class="hints">[HINT]</div>

        <br>
        <br>
       <button id=”MYsubmit” type="button" onclick="finalsubmit()">submit</button>
    <div id="score"></div>
    <div id="COPYRIGHT">Copyright © 2019. All rights reserved</div>

</form> 








</body>
<script src="includes/scripts.js"></script>

</html>
```

. I would like the dark blue backgrounds touching each other, and I would like my radio buttons moved so they are below the answers,also I would like to do the same with the hint, and welcome comment. Im new with css so i apologize if its done poorly, im having a hard time figuring this one out and would appreciate any help. thank you guys alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, skipped the animations but got it working using this code below:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#hint2').hover(function() {

    $(this).text("hover text");
  },
  function() {

    $(this).text("back to origonal");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use tooltip? Example from w3schools

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;

  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltip">HINT
  <span class="tooltiptext">Put your hint here</span>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply I appreciate your help, but im specifically looking to use jquery bro

Comment: How about try this
$("#hint1").on("mouseover", function () {
    alert("HINT");
});

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you should just use Tooltip instead of mouseover ^^

[JQuery Tooltip](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/)

> $("#hint1").tooltip();

with `title` as attribute for the texts.

[Here's the Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/NeonNature/pen/moOQjm)

Comment: thanks for the reply I appreciate your help, but im specifically looking to use jquery bro for the animation

Comment: This is JQuery too. It automatically adds the fade in/fade out animation for the tooltip. (Oi. You're Myanmar, too?)  Anyway, do you mean special CSS stylings?

Comment: I've updated the example with a codepen demo. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Not exactly bro, I found a close enough solution using j query so im going to stick with that